# Why does kafka-console-consumer timeout on a small number of messages?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am doing testing and only have 300 messages in a kafka topic. When trying to show that count the `kafka-console-consumer` command times out:

```
$kafka-console-consumer  --from-beginning   --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property print.key=true  --property print.value=false --property print.partition --topic air2008 --timeout-ms 20000 | tail -n 10
[2019-05-10 22:55:01,646] ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException
Processed a total of 300 messages
2008-06-05_730
2008-06-05_332
2008-06-15_1669
2008-06-12_1637
2008-06-21_227
2008-06-25_542
2008-06-17_1790
2008-06-22_1058
2008-06-04_1676
```

What is actually happening here/ what is being waited for?  I can change the timeout from 20seconds to higher (e.g. 60seconds) or lower (e.g 1 second) - but gets same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the exception just means that no new messages came in during the timeout duration you set.  This isn't an error so much as a notification.

Comment: makes sense - so i'll keep a 1000ms timeout for now

Comment: Am I the only one that finds it incredibly irritating for the console consumer to throw an exception like this as an FYI, with no way to tell it "hey, I'm expecting to read everything, timeout is not exceptional, please don't tell me about it" ?? I mean, I don't really want to send stderr to /dev/null, but what choice do I have (that isn't overly-complicated) if I want to keep this unnecessary exception + stack trace  out of my logs?